# Длина строки в чистом C

Tags: c

У меня есть такой прототип функции: `int len(const char *string);`. Как мне ее реализовать ? Я ведь знаю только адрес первого символа. Могу ли я как-то узнать сколько их всего ?

Comment: Нужно искать терминирующий ноль.

Comment: Если `string` указывает на начало *строки*, то надо просто пройти по строке до терминирующего нуля. А уж реализовать это можно сотней разных способов. Вопрос тут скорее в том, зачем вам нужно реализовывать то, что уже реализовано стандартной функцией.

Comment: Все комментарии и ответы неполны. Вы не указали кодировку символов. Без этих данных всё сказанное провалится на первом же тесте с UTF-16 или UCS2.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, AnT, нет, это зависит. Если кодировка предполагает нулевые байты в потоке, то длину надо передавать отдельно.

Comment: @0andriy, тип данных однозначно указан, это явно не UTF-16 или UCS2

Comment: @bukkojot в Си указатель -- это просто адрес участка памяти и тип данных. Для POD указатели взаимоприводимы (dynamic cast), поэтому ваш вывод неточен.

Comment: Вот ещё один веский аргумент, строки в utf-8 терминированы нулём, и все приведенные ответы -- чушь в таком случае.

Comment: @Ant, почитайте мои коментарии (особенно сегодняшние) в этом вопросе-ответах. Весьма занятная, оказывается, задача.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Можете, но только **если вызывающий совершенно точно даёт вам именно строку**.

В Си всякая строка является массивом символов.
Но не всякий массив символов можно считать строкой.

На уровне системы типов Си не различает их вовсе. Всё держится на уговоре, что в конце указанной (началом) области памяти **точно есть** нуль-символ, в противном случае считать её строкой не следует, и работать с ней даже стандартными функциями для строк опасно.

О сишных строках известно, что:

- Символы в них идут в памяти подряд по возрастанию указателей.
- Первый встреченный символ с кодом 0 (нуль-символ) — конец строки.
- Каждый символ содержится в одном `char`'е. Это здорово ограничивает множество совместимых кодировок (из известных русскоязычных на ПК: Windows-1251, CP866, KOI8-r), но для учебных задач это часто предполагают. Если строка окажется, например, в UTF-8, функция не упадёт (т. к. нуль там такой же), но результат может дать неверный (если ожидается число символов).

Считать ли завершающий ноль как занимающий длину... есть аргументы в обе стороны.

- С одной стороны, этот нуль-символ не входит в "полезную нагрузку" строки, это чисто служебный элемент. **Общепринято, так считает `strlen`.**
- С другой, нуль-символ занимает место и его существование нужно учитывать при выделении пространства для хранения.

Comment: Наивно полагать, что символ == байт.

Comment: @0andriy как и полагать, что байт будет 8-битным. Как и полагать, что преподаватель, это задание давший, сам учитывает это.

Comment: Про преподавателя категорически согласен. Про *байт* уже перегиб (формально вы правы), я понимаю ваше желание защитить ответ, но нет, замените термином *октет* в моём комментарии, и вся суть останется прежней. Да и банально подумайте об utf-8.

Comment: @0andriy останется, но и мой посыл останется прежним – это такой же ненужный в этой ситуации "перегиб", как отвергнуть предположение о размере байта.

Comment: Нет, не приравнивайте часто встречаемую проблему с перегибами ради перегибов. Говнокод плодить нынче модно. (Это относится и к "преподавателям", часто не владеющим материалом, и, как следствие, неумением составить грамотно постановку задачи)

Comment: @0andriy ок, оставил ещё пункт, предупреждающий о суровой реальности. Лучше?

Comment: Да, так лучше! Спасибо.

Comment: Вы будете смеяться, но ваш ответ, хотя и самый лучший среди приведенных здесь, не отвечает на вопрос. Мне друг указал, что я весьма поверхностно копнул, и кодировки — лишь  вершина айсберга. (Плюс я, конечно, вам оставил, хотя тема гораздо обширнее)

Comment: Если интересно, поищите ответ на вопрос, сколько юникодных кодов в кириллической букве "ё" или "й".

Comment: @0andriy если выражаться в терминах Юникода, то под "символами" имеются в виду скорее "графемы". Так что Юникодные строки не могут быть представлены в классическом сишном виде вообще, поскольку в графеме может быть произвольное число кодов. Не вижу смысла углублять ответ в эту сторону далее.

Comment: (Не слышал термина "графемы", слышал "глифы", а вот тут и разница описана https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84) Конечно, ведь суть сводится к вопросу "Для **чего** мы считаем длину строки?" В зависимости от этого мы можем получать раличные результаты для **одного и того же набора байт (октетов)**. Скорее всего преподаватель либо ожидает от студентов правильных вопросов (оптимистичный вариант), либо "плавает" в теме сам. И поэтому ответ, который вы дали, устроит ~95+% аудитории.

Comment: @0andriy в Юникоде это разные вещи. Графема может состоять из множества глифов. Т. е. глиф -- "атом" графического представления графем. Он относится уже к отрисовке, а не к представлению в данных. Я подозреваю, что преподаватель не считает нужным сообщать о дополнительных сложностях, чтобы студенты могли собирать практичные алгоритмы хотя бы в "игрушечной" среде. О проблемах реальности студентов стоит предупредить, но в подробностях рассказать о них лучше уже после курса.

Comment: *By comparison, a specific shape that represents any particular grapheme in a specific typeface is called a glyph.* То есть один-в-один отображение. Откуда про множество?

Comment: @0andriy важно то, что глиф -- штука чисто графическая и с данными связана слабо. Возможны ситуации, в которых, глиф представляет несколько графем разом: ["the sequence <f, i> may be displayed as a single glyph on the screen, but would still be two grapheme clusters"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries). А классический случай, когда одна графема может быть про несколько глифов: всякие акцентные символы. Но это зависит от шрифта и отрисовывающего движка, типичные акцентированные символы обычно имеют отдельные глифы, но взгляните на Залго. Там глифов не напасёшься :)

Comment: Да, интересно, спасибо за ссылки.

Comment: @0andriy в вашей фразе "графема" из типографики, а не из Юникода. Конфликт терминов. По-хорошему, в нём виноват я, т. к. из юникода более точным переводом будет скорее "графемный кластер". Но мне лениво печатать это каждый раз, и на длинных терминах легко потерять нить :\

Answer (score 6):

Последним будет нулевой символ - это определение строки C.

Т.е. ваша функция будет иметь примерно следующий вид:

```
int len(const char *string)
{
    const char * с = string;
    while(*c) ++c;
    return с - string;
}
```

Можно добавить "защиту от дурака" - например, проверку, не нулевой ли указатель `string`...

Comment: Не занимайтесь изобретением велосипедов, используйте библиотечные функции, написанные профессионалами.

Comment: @bukkojot И уж обязательно делайте это тогда, когда преподаватели требуют от вас написать свою реализацию! Как иначе ставить этих дураков на место? Еще, конечно, можно просто сказать преподу, что он кретин - тоже неплохо действует...

Comment: Совершенно верно! А наш герой пусть учиться в учебном заведении.

Comment: @bukkojot Думаю, вы хотели написать "пусть учится"?..

Comment: И вообще решение неточное, как и условие задачи.

Answer (score 4):

```
int len(const char *string){
   return strlen(string);
}
```

Comment: Нет, ваше решение неточное как и условие задачи.

Comment: Моё решение является клеем между некорректным заданием и правильной реализацией. Более правильное решение я опубликовал в отдельном посте, однако его заминусовали.

Comment: Я зануда, я про кодировки, а из двух более правильное как раз это.

Comment: @0andriy: А в какой кодировке возможны промежуточные нули? UTF-16 не подойдёт, т. к. нам передан указатель на узкий символ.

Comment: @VladD, я написал в комментарии к ТС что это ничего не значит по большому счёту. Ещё раз, без указания кодировки задание некорректно. Если, например, кодировка us-ascii, то как считать байт 0x80 в потоке? Да даже банально utf-8, все ответы - чушь в таком случае.

Comment: @VladD Когда уже и новички, и советчики поймут, что символ (текста) != байт даже для однобайтовых кодировок? (Вопрос риторический)

Comment: Ты еще кодировки по 5 бит вспомни

Comment: Не передёргивайте. Хотите чему-то научиться? Почитайте и изучите тему.

Comment: @0andriy: Ну, давайте разделим подсчёт количества символов и поиск нуля, это всё же отдельные вещи. Промежуточных нулей в известных мне кодировках нет (хотя я не исключаю, что есть и совсем странные кодировки). Сишная традиция, однако же, состоит в том, что строки являются неинтерпретируемыми массивами данных, и без дополнительного указания кодировки считается один char = один символ. Системные функции из `<string.h>` все исходят из ASCIIZ-строк по одному символу на char/wchar_t/...

Comment: Системные функции __str*()__ — это тяжёлое наследие из костылей и граблей. Один ctype чего стоит только... (именно по причине **символ != байт (октет)**)

Comment: @0andriy: Да, сишные строки оставляют желать лучшего. Но так уж исторически сложилось. Я даже не знаю, проникли ли кодировки наподобие utf-8 в сишный стандарт, или использование под них `char*` является самодеятельностью библиотек.

Comment: А что, utf-8 как-то несовместим со стандартными функциями? У 0andriy получается слишком толсто.

Comment: @bukkojot, это не толсто, это против говнокода. Наревьювитесь с моё, ещё не так будете плеваться на подобное. Впрочем, судя по вашим комментариям... http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Ну, с одной стороны, личный наезд не прибавляет баллов вам, а лычки эксперта греют душу мне. И если бросаться друг в друга ссылками, то наверное это будет точнее и поучительнее: https://ebanoe.it/2017/02/09/how-to-oppress-developers/

Comment: @bukkojot: Ну, для utf-8 например получение подстроки может «разрезать» многобайтный символ. С точки зрения однобайтной строки это не проблема, но с точки зрения utf-8 нехорошо.

Comment: @bukkojot, если бы это был ваш первый комментарий в таком стиле, то я может быть и согласился с вами, а так... Моя картина мира включает в себя "если мне говорят, что я в чём-то не прав или чего-то не понимаю, я прошу либо ссылки на документацию, либо себе сам стараюсь ответить на эти вопросы". Кстати, мне вот как раз друг указал, что я тоже в этой тебе не глубоко копнул, и даже кодировки — лишь вершина айсберга. Владельцы MacBook (iOS устройств с файловой системой) могут проверить в консоли весёлости юникода и подсчёта длин строк.

Comment: @VladD, так выбирайте подстроку по границе символа (причем он может быть составным, т.е. ждать отсутствия высшего бита недостаточно, это будет лишь граница кода). А так как ютф8 полностью совместим со старыми однобайтовыми кодировками, то старые добрые функции str*() продолжают работать.

Comment: @0andriy, переходы на личности резко убавляют у вас баллов, попробуйте без них, а то мне даже ответить не на что.

Comment: @bukkojot, дело ваше, могу лишь вас процитировать *А что, utf-8 как-то несовместим со стандартными функциями? У 0andriy получается слишком толсто.* То есть вместо поиска ответа на вопросы вы а) занялись демонстрацией невежества и б) фактическим ярлыком тролля на человека, который объясняет вам почему ваш ответ не годится. (И это ещё не вспоминая ваш изначальный фамилиарный тон)

Comment: @bukkojot: Ну я это понимаю, но есть же strncpy из стандартной библиотеки, она может (с точки зрения utf-8) и подсчитать неправильно, и разрезать не там.

Answer (score 2):

Можете. Строки в С заканчиваются символом \0. Итого код будет таким

```
int len(const char *string) {
  int res = 0;
  while (*string++)
    res++;
  return res;
}
```

Или с использованием стандартной функции `strlen()`

```
int len(const char *string) {
  return strlen(string);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Самое правильное решение:

```
#define len strlen
```

Comment: Господа минусующие, а вы не подумали, насколько корректны другие решения? Что будет, если препод решит потестировать эту функцию при помощи строки более 2 гигабайт? А вот моё решение корректно отработает! У вас есть возражения? Сможете парировать это?

Comment: Да. Как минимум, это решение не соответствует данному в вопросе прототипу функции. Да, из условия следует, что поддержка двухгиговых строк функцией `len` ненадёжна. Щито поделать.

Comment: Этим займется компилятор

Comment: Это совершенно неважно.

Comment: Это плохое решение, так как препроцессор "прячет" проверку типов. Более корректное *static inline ...*, поэтому с "минусами" согласен.